# Getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" format exception, importing data from csv file

Tags: c#, csv, datetime

Here is the code block where the exception is being thrown:

```
DateTime rentInDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/0001");
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParse(masterArray[11], out rentInDate);

if (isValid)
{
  masters[masterCount] = new Car(
                           int.Parse(masterArray[0]), 
                           masterArray[1], 
                           new Customer(int.Parse(masterArray[2]), masterArray[3]), 
                           int.Parse(masterArray[4]),
                           masterArray[5], 
                           masterArray[6], 
                           int.Parse(masterArray[7]), 
                           int.Parse(masterArray[8]),
                           decimal.Parse(masterArray[9]), 
                           Convert.ToDateTime(masterArray[10]), 
                           rentInDate);
}
```

In this code, I am calling in an array of data from a csv file. The dates are the last two data points in the array and their values are respectively 1/1/2017 and 1/7/2017. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use TryParse for both DaeTime values.

Comment: On _which_ line you get this exception exactly?

Comment: Any of the many wonderful already built CSV Parsing tools will parse the file and convert to the proper type for you

Comment: @SonerGönül The exception doesn't tell me specifically but I think it's probably "Convert.ToDateTime(masterArray[10])" as I didn't have a problem doing a WriteLine() w/ the rentInDate element.